# Why AWS creating a duplicate Launch template and use it in nodegroup instead of the launchtemplate defined in cfn template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I am trying to create a managed nodegroup with custom launch template. However AWS creeates two launch templates when i used the template to create resources via cloudformation. One with the launchtemplate configuration and another with prefix "eks-"

[image]

Here is my cfn template to create the same.

```
................
................
................
Parameters:
  EKSStackName:
  Type: String
  NodeVolumeSize:
  Type: String
  KeyName:
  Type: String

NodeGroup:
Type: AWS::EKS::Nodegroup
Properties:
  AmiType: AL2_x86_64
  ClusterName: 
    Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${EKSStackName}::ControlPlaneName"   
  ForceUpdateEnabled: false
  NodegroupName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ManagedNodeGroup"
  NodeRole: !GetAtt NodeInstanceRole.Arn
  ScalingConfig:
    DesiredSize: 2
    MaxSize: 10
    MinSize: 2
  Subnets: !Split
    - ","
    - !Ref VPCPrivateSubnets
  LaunchTemplate:
    Id: !Ref NodeLaunchTemplate
    Version: !GetAtt NodeLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber

................
................
................

NodeLaunchTemplate:
Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
Properties:
  LaunchTemplateName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-launch-template"
  LaunchTemplateData:
    InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
    KeyName: !Ref KeyName
    BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: !Ref NodeVolumeSize
          VolumeType: gp2
          DeleteOnTermination: true
    SecurityGroupIds:
    - !Ref NodeSecurityGroup        
    TagSpecifications:
    - ResourceType: instance
      Tags:
      - Key: eks:cluster-name
        Value: 
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${EKSStackName}::ControlPlaneName"
      - Key: eks:nodegroup-name
        Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ManagedNodeGroup"
    - ResourceType: volume
      Tags:
      - Key: eks:cluster-name
        Value: 
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${EKSStackName}::ControlPlaneName"
      - Key: eks:nodegroup-name
        Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ManagedNodeGroup"
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

        --==MYBOUNDARY==
        Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

        #!/bin/bash
        set +e
        set -x
        INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
        REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|jq -c -r .region)
        NODEGROUP_NAME=$(aws ec2 describe-instances  --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[?Key==`eks:nodegroup-name`].Value' --region $REGION --output text)
        WORKER_STACK_NAME="${!NODEGROUP_NAME%-*}"
        EKS_STACK_NAME=$(aws ec2 describe-instances  --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[?Key==`eks:cluster-name`].Value' --region $REGION --output text)
        
        
        # AWS Vars
        DOCKER_DAEMON=/etc/docker/daemon.json
        JOURNALD_CONF=/etc/systemd/journald.conf

        # Adjust rate limiting parameters for journald and syslog on host
        sed -i 's/#RateLimitInterval=30s/RateLimitInterval=5s/g' $JOURNALD_CONF
        sed -i 's/#RateLimitBurst=1000/RateLimitBurst=2000/g' $JOURNALD_CONF
        
        systemctl restart systemd-journald
        systemctl restart rsyslog

       # Set log-drive for docker containers to journald
       echo '{"no-new-privileges":true,"bridge":"none","userland-proxy":false,"log-driver":"journald","log-opts":{"labels":"LOCATION","env":"Test"}}' > $DOCKER_DAEMON
       systemctl enable   docker
       systemctl restart  docker

       # Install SSM agent
       sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
        

       -==MYBOUNDARY==--
```

However the cfn creates 2 launchtemplates. One with above user data and other with above user data merged with AWS EKS user data. The name of this template typically looks like an UUID prefixed with eks. (Eg: eks-f8ce4f5c-1722-b432-0fee-f535bbcrf317) It is the later that is being referenced in my nodegroup. The 'additional' default userdata is to attach the ec2 instances for cluster.

Example:

```
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

 --==MYBOUNDARY==
 Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
 <custom userdata>

 --==MYBOUNDARY==
 Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
 #!/bin/bash
 set -ex
 B64_CLUSTER_CA=LS0tLSSUZJQ0Fxxxxxxx
 API_SERVER_URL=https://1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0Fxxxxxxx
 K8S_CLUSTER_DNS_IP=10.100.0.10
 /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh <stackname>-ControlPlane-EKSControlPlane --kubelet-extra-args '--node-labels=eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateVersion=1,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-0e9322442a96411f0,eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=<prefix>-NodeGroup-ManagedNodeGroup,eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateId=lt-0a70c3br71460c46k' --b64-cluster-ca $B64_CLUSTER_CA --apiserver-endpoint $API_SERVER_URL --dns-cluster-ip $K8S_CLUSTER_DNS_IP
```

The AWS EKS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html) (unde Specifying an AMI) section says Only in case of following requirement cases one nee to provide custom AMI id in launch template instead of AMI_TYPE in nodegroup.

1. If you have either of the following requirements, then specify an AMI ID in the imageId field of your launch template. Select the requirement you have for additional information.
2. Run a custom AMI due to specific security, compliance, or internal policy requirements

Interestingly, in the ec2 instance logs, for bootstrap.sh command under kubelet-extra-args, for eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateId the value of original launch template is assigned instead of the launch template id that is being referenced by nodegroup.

Log snippet:

```
etc/eks/bootstrap.sh <prefix>-ControlPlane-EKSControlPlane --kubelet-extra-args --node-labels=eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateVersion=1,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-0e9322442a96411f0,eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=<prefix>-NodeGroup-ManagedNodeGroup,eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateId=lt-0a70c3br71460c46k --b64-cluster-ca <b64 cluster ca> --apiserver-endpoint https://48VB93B7DE9A4E03441923170AD20664.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com --dns-cluster-ip 10.100.0.10
```

Comment: If you are open to alternative which will call the template on your behalf, try: `eksctl create nodegroup -r <region> --cluster <cluster name> --managed --name <new managed nodegroup name>`. This command will create a managedNodeGroup for you on existing cluster. To customize instance type etc, see [here](https://eksctl.io/usage/eks-managed-nodes/).

Comment: No. This is a series of stacks created by a shell script thru aws-cli. So can't take exception for one stack.